# JS: how to implement a multidimensional array of inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

how to implement a multidimensional array of inputs in a pure javascript function?

for example, I have this:

```
 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[0][0][price]' value='100'>
 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[0][0][count]' value='1'>

 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[0][1][price]' value='300'>
 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[0][1][count]' value='5'>

 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[1][0][price]' value='2000'>
 <input type='text' class="order" name='order[1][0][count]' value='2'>
```

I want to store inputs in a javascript array and then, working with that array like this:

I tried this:

```
   const nodes = [
     0 => [0 => ['price' => 100,'count' => 1]],
     0 => [1 => ['price' => 300,'count' => 5]],
     1 => [0 => ['price' => 2000,'count' => 2]]
   ];

    var total_prices = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        total_prices[i] = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < nodes[i].length; j++) {
            total_prices[i] += nodes[i][j][price];
       }
    }
```

how can fill **nodes**  via inputs?

Comment: You tried that in javascript?

Comment: What syntax is this from?  `const nodes = [0 => [0 => ['price' => 100,'count' => 1]],
     0 => [1 => ['price' => 300,'count' => 5]],
     1 => [0 => ['price' => 2000,'count' => 2]]
   ];`

Comment: @zer00ne seems like an associative array in PHP.